# Ionic 2: Why does it add .fixed-content and .scroll-content

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Ionic seems to be adding a `<div class='fixed-content'>` and `<div class='scroll-content'>` to my view and it's creating double margins.  It seems to just add a lot of content and I'm assuming I can control it, I just don't know how.

**Why would that happen?**

my html:

```
<ion-content>
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col >
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
          <img [src]="client.get_image.before_front_full || '../assets/newred_newblue_outline.png'">
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
          <img [src]="client.get_image.before_side_full || '../assets/newred_newblue_outline.png'">
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
          <img [src]="client.get_image.after_front_full || '../assets/newred_newblue_outline.png'">
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
          <img [src]="client.get_image.after_side_full || '../assets/newred_newblue_outline.png'">
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

rendered content:

```
<ion-content class="content content-md">

<!-- DOUBLE MARGIN... WHY?! -->
<div class="fixed-content" style="margin-top: 56px; margin-bottom: 61px;"></div>
<div class="scroll-content" style="margin-top: 56px; margin-bottom: 61px;">
<ion-grid class="fill-height grid">
  <ion-row class="row">
    <ion-col class="col">
      <ion-card class="card card-md">
        <ion-card-content class="card-content card-content-md">
          <img src="http://awaken180-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/clients/before_fronts/000/000/067/original/marty.jpg?1490189112">
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col class="col">
      <ion-card class="card card-md">
        <ion-card-content class="card-content card-content-md">
          <img src="../assets/newred_newblue_outline.png">
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col class="col">
      <ion-card class="card card-md">
        <ion-card-content class="card-content card-content-md">
          <img src="../assets/newred_newblue_outline.png">
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col class="col">
      <ion-card class="card card-md">
        <ion-card-content class="card-content card-content-md">
          <img src="../assets/newred_newblue_outline.png">
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `Ionic2` adds both `fixed-content` and `scroll-content`.

The `fixed-content` as the name says it's the content on the page that is fixed, if it's adding both margin to top and bottom it's because you have a header and a footer on this page, and it adds exactly the amount of px it's needed to leave the space for your header and footer on your device. So if you check on a device it may be `36px`, on anothe it's `72px`. If you want to test, remove the footer or header and check again, it'll not have margin top or bottom.

The `scroll-content` is where the scrollable content is, in this case, your `ion-content`. Everything inside ion-content is scrollable and added on `scroll-content`.

You can force css to it (i use the `fixed-content` class to add a non-scrollable background image to some projects), but it's not something nice to do because it'll make your content on the page go up, so if you have content right bellow the header it may be initialized behind the header.

So that's why `Ionic2` creates these classes, it's just to ensure that your scrollable content goes right where it needs to be.

Comment: How can you remove this style=bottom-margin:134px in the fixed-content scroll-content classes using CSS ? because for one of the tabs I am hiding the tab footer via a service `tabs[key].style.transform = 'translateY(156px)';` even though I have a ion-header in the template of this tab the content fills all the way to the top. It just the bottom that has creeped on me on device rotation. I cannot seem to target it with CSS

Comment: I tried Content.resize on Platform.resize but it does not seem to fix the problem perhaps because the actual content to fill the whole screen is coming from child components? So this content.resize is not propagated down???

Comment: I got rid of the bottom-margin by calling again my TabsService.Hide() on the Platform.resize  which also does ` scrollContent[key].style.marginBottom = '0';`

If you have an All CSS approach I would like to test out.  Thank you.